# NumPy - Excluding all zero 2D arrays from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple 3D arrays with different shapes but I'm going to assume I have an array named `A` with shape `(53, 768, 768)` for an example. It consists of 53 2D arrays and some of them may be empty images. Those empty images have only 0 pixel values.

If there are `N` slices with all 0 values, I want to slice `A` into a `(53 - N, 768, 768)` 3D array. Is this possible with indexing?

I tried something like this `a[:, ~np.all(a == 0)]`, but it returns an array with shape `(53, 1, 768, 768)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data is something like this:

```py
z = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
])
```

The shape of `z` is `(4, 2, 3)`. We therefore need a vector with shape `4`, aggregating over the other dimensions. We can use the `axis=` parameter in most Numpy functions for this:

```py
mask = np.all(z != 0, axis=(1, 2))
a[mask]
```

In this example, `mask` will be `array([False, False,  True, False])`.

Axes are numbered 0, 1, 2, etc. So we use 1 and 2 to refer to the 2nd and 3rd axes.

You can also use negative numbers as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63245657/2954547); if you write `axis=(-2, -1)` that refers to the last and 2nd-to-last axes, i.e. axes 1 and 2 in this example.

In general, use `axis=` to specify which axes are to be collapsed by aggregating. Any axis not specified in `axis=` will not be aggregated.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(A)                                 # if A is not a NumPy array
result = A[np.sum(A, axis = (-1, -2)) != 0]
```

This will do.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly but the other answer is more thorough so I accepted it.